# How to show this limit exists and differentiate after change of coordinates?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

This is homework, I'm unsure of the method not looking for an entire solution as I do wish to be able to do this myself.

I'm unsure how to show the limit of this function exists

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{\cosh(x)-\cos(y)}{(1+ x^2 + y^2)^{1/3}} - 1$$

so I set $y=0$ and approached as $x\to0$ and got $3/2$ and then I set $x=0$ and approached $y\to0$ and also got $3/2$. Which suggests it exists and is $3/2$.

But as we learned in class its not enough to just approach from 2 curves, so I'm unsure how to show limit actually does exist. Is there there some sort of substitution? I thought maybe polar coordinates and let $r\to0$ but I'm just unsure how I'd actually differentiate this function if I substitute $x=r\cosθ$ and $y=r\sinθ$ as I'd need to use L'Hospitals rule as its indeterminate in current form using that substitution and would need to differentiate it multiple times and looks like get quite big expression quite quickly and I'm unsure how the angle will affect the process .

Is anyone able to explain how I can show that this limit exists? Must I use polar coordinates and if so how will the differentiation work? $\cosθ$ and $\sinθ$ will be constants but will they drop out and leave me with $3/2$ if this is in fact the limit?